# User defined function performance disadvantages

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, function, user-defined-functions

I have a database with a lot of UDFs that contains a long running process involving lots of data manipulation and calculations.

My thinking in using UDFs is to separate out logical units of information from the tables underlying.  For example, if i am trying to get information about a car i might have several tables like Color, Model, Year, etc that i would have to join each time to get a Car.  Instead, I would have a function like fnCar() to get a denormalized view of the data.

I call these functions a lot during my long running process and I'm wondering if it would be better if instead I had a denormalized working table,view, or temp table to do my data manipulation and calculations.  Is there some disadvantage to using UDFs in general that I should be aware of in terms of performance?

For example, I make some calculations using a UDF.  I then unpivot that data and store in a table.  Whenever i need to use that data again, I call a UDF to pivot the data back out.  The reason we do it this way is to keep our calculations flexible.  We don't want to change the data model if we add/remove/change the calculations.

```
--Calculate some values in a function

declare @location table
(
    id int,
    lattitude float,
    longitude float
)

insert into @location select  1, 40.7, 74
insert into @location select  2, 42, 73
insert into @location select  3, 61, 149
insert into @location select  4, 41, 87


declare @myLattitude float
declare @myLongitude float
set @myLattitude =43
set @myLongitude = 116

declare @distance table
(
    id int,
    distance float
)

insert into @distance
select id, sqrt(power(lattitude-@mylattitude,2)+power(longitude-@mylongitude,2))
from @location



--Store unpivoted data in a table
declare @unpivot table
(
    id int,
    attribute varchar(100),
    attributeValue float
)

insert into @unpivot
(
    id,
    attribute,
    attributeValue
)
select id
    ,attribute
    ,attributevalue 
from
(
    select 
        L.id,
        L.Lattitude, 
        L.Longitude,
        D.Distance
    from @location L 
        inner join @distance D 
        on L.id=D.id
) a
unpivot 
(
    attributeValue for attribute in
    (lattitude, longitude, distance)
) x

--retrive data from store via pivoting function for reporting

select * 
from @unpivot
pivot 
(
    max(attributeValue) for Attribute in (lattitude, longitude, distance)

) x
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague.  You seem to have performance issues with a complex system.  UDFs could be the problem, but you don't provide enough information.  Can you provide an example of what the data looks like and what the UDFs are?

Comment: provided an example.  it's not exactly representative of the calculations we're performing, but suffice it to say we're doing many complex calculations and want to be able to add/remove them without modifying the underlying table structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll attempt an answer

Simply: *You are doing it wrong with UDFs*

When you use UDFs, then you add these problems

1. RBAR (see bottom) processing
   When you use scalar UDFs with table access in the SELECT clause
   That is, instead of an efficient JOIN, you force a table lookip *per row"
2. Black box processing with multi-statement TVFs
   Each TVF has to run to completion and is considered a "black box"

What you *normally* do is to load a flat staging table and then JOIN to lookup tables the processing is done as a set. If this is what you mean by "denormalised" then yes, it probably works better.

Using UDFs for "logical units of information" is OO/Procedural thinking. SQL is set based. What appears OK for an object or collection of objects running in native/CLR code **fails** for set based data processing via a query optimiser.

Note: RBAR = Row By Agonising Row. For more, see [Simple Talk's article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)

Comment: Having read this article recently, I feel compelled to post it and say, "not necessarily".  But it IS probable that the way he's using them is causing performance problems.

    http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/

Comment: +1 I think some of the reasons for using UDFs are sound, but usually they come from the "encapsulate everything" mindset and less attention might be paid to performance implications of obscuring it from SQL Server and preventing it from applying the function logic on the entire set.

Comment: If we wants to encapsulate particular views of the data, then "views" are the right approach, not UDFs.  But without more information about how they are being used, it is really hard to make generalizations.

Comment: I don't have the RBAR problem since almost all the UDFs are TVFs.  I didn't know about the black box problem.  If the underlying tables are very large, say millions of (short) rows, would i get any performance advantage/disadvantage to having a TVF return just a subset of the table that i can join to in subsequent queries?

Comment: gordon, why is a view better than a function in the case you described?  Is there some optimization done on the view that is not done on the function?

Comment: @FistOfFury: An *inline* TVF is just a macro that expands like a view would. You may hide the number of JOINs because of this, but avoid RBAR processing

Comment: @GordonLinoff: An inline TVF and non-indexed view are identical in behaviour in SQL Server

Comment: @gbn thanks for that last comment. that was what i was trying to ask.  I suppose i should refactor the functions into views only if i plan to put indices on them.

Comment: @FistOfFury: then you'll need NOEXPAND hints on standard edition. Or to force use of them in Enterprise. perhaps go back to square one and rethink the approach. I suggest asking for help on dba.se too http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gbn: Did you mean *", but **not** avoid RBAR processing."* above?

Comment: @gbn . . . TVFs may be treated by the query processor as being identical.  However, they are not the same thing.  Their metadata is stored entirely differently.  You cannot find them in INFORMATION_SCEHMA.tables, for example.  I believe that they have different permissions from views.  And less knowledgeable users of SQL would be hard-pressed to find them in SSMS.

Comment: @ypercube: No, RBAR is cursor like actions caused by scalar UDFs. Inline TVFs and views expand to give more complex JOINs.