# Access 2007 user-defined function over join slow

Tags: performance, join, ms-access-2007, user-defined-functions

Why is a query using a user-defined function over a query with several joins including outer joins slow? The reason for the function is to modify a string so that it sorts numerically. Sorting a string means that `100 < 99`. The function reformats `99 as 099`. So, `099 < 100`. It lets other non-numeric values remain unchanged.

The problem query uses a function over a query with joins. It takes 27 seconds to return 100 rows. The same query, with a function, but over one table takes subsecond. A SQL-replacement for the query over the query with joins is subsecond. A query without the function over the query with joins is subsecond. The primary table is tblTests with 517 rows. The column that the function operates on is a text column fldPurity.

```
tblTests
fldTestsID    autonumber
fldPurity     Text.  field size 50. Indexed (Duplicates OK). Zero Length No.
```

Here is the function code. Notice the different inputs.

```
Public Function SortablePercent(ByVal pVar As Variant) As String
'------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:   Formats a string that may contain numbers or text values.
'            The string percent may contain % or + characters. Ignore
'            those characters during comparison. A string may start with numeric
'            characters, but end with alpha characters. Compute the length of the resulting
'            numeric characters. Length 3 is 100, no change. Prepend leading zeros to length 2
'            or 1 numerics. Do not add prepend to values starting with text.

' Coded by:  2013-08-05 Henry Helgen
' Arguments: pVar: The string to be formatted.
' To Test:   From the debug (immediate) window:
'            X = "97+%"
'            ? SortablePercent(X)
'            097
'            X = "98"
'            ? SortablePercent(X)
'            098
'            X = "99.9"
'            ? SortablePercent(X)
'            099.9
'            X = "100"
'            Print SortablePercent(X)
'            100
'            X = "Reagent Grade"
'            ? SortablePercent(X)
'            Reagent Grade
'            X = "85% & 15% H2O"
'            ? SortablePercent(X)
'            085 & 15 H2O
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strHold As String 'working string
Dim lenNum  As Integer 'length of leading integer portion of number

    ' remove whitespace, %, + characters
    strHold = Replace(Replace(Nz(Trim(pVar), ""), "%", ""), "+", "")

    If IsNumeric(strHold) Then 'the entire string is numeric
        lenNum = Len(CStr(Int(strHold)))
        'Fill with leading zeros
        strHold = Switch(lenNum = 3, strHold, lenNum = 2, "0" & strHold, lenNum = 1, "00" & strHold)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(strHold, 2)) Then '
        strHold = "0" & strHold
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(strHold, 1)) Then
        strHold = "00" & strHold
    End If 'numeric

    SortablePercent = strHold

End Function
```

Here is slow query using function over query with joins (27 seconds)

```
SELECT parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure.fldPurity, 
       SortablePercent([fldPurity]) AS temp2, Count(*) AS RcdCount
FROM parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure
GROUP BY parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure.fldPurity, 
         SortablePercent([fldPurity])
ORDER BY SortablePercent([fldPurity]);
```

Here is fast query using function over one table (<1 second)

```
SELECT tblTests.fldPurity, 
       SortablePercent([fldPurity]) AS temp2, 
       Count(*) AS RcdCount
FROM tblTests
GROUP BY tblTests.fldPurity, SortablePercent([fldPurity])
ORDER BY SortablePercent([fldPurity]);
```

Here is fast query without function over query with joins (<1 second)

```
SELECT parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure.fldPurity, 
       Count(*) AS RcdCount
FROM parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure
GROUP BY parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure.fldPurity;
```

Here is fast query using SQL partial approximation of function over one table (<1 second)

```
SELECT tblTests.fldPurity, 
       IIf(IsNumeric(Replace(Replace(Nz(Trim([fldPurity]),""),"%",""),"+","")),CDbl(Replace(Replace(Trim([fldPurity]),"%",""),"+","")),Trim([fldPurity])) AS tempPurity, 
       Count(*) AS RcdCount
FROM tblTests
GROUP BY tblTests.fldPurity
ORDER BY IIf(IsNumeric(Replace(Replace(Nz(Trim([fldPurity]),""),"%",""),"+","")),CDbl(Replace(Replace(Trim([fldPurity]),"%",""),"+","")),Trim([fldPurity]));
```

Here is the query with joins

```
SELECT q_Test.fldTestsID, q_DatasetTreatment.fldDatasetsID, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldExposureEffectsID, q_Test.fldValidated, 
       q_Test.fldPollutantID, q_Test.fldPollutantName, q_Test.fldPollutantCAS, 
       q_Test.fldModeOfActionID, q_Test.fldModeOfAction, q_Test.fldPollutantTypeID, 
       q_Test.fldPollutantType, q_Test.fldSpeciesID, q_Test.fldClass, q_Test.fldGenus,
       q_Test.fldSpecies, q_Test.fldCommonName, q_Test.fldTestTypeID, 
       q_Test.fldTestType, q_Test.fldTechniqueID, q_Test.fldTechnique,
       q_Test.fldConcUnits, q_Test.fldDescription AS fldConcUnitDescription,
       q_Test.fldMRID, q_Test.fldCETISID, q_Test.fldHardness, q_Test.fldSalinity, 
       q_Test.fldpH, q_Test.fldTemperature, q_Test.fldPurity, q_Test.fldDO, 
       q_Test.fldAcute, q_Test.fldUser, q_Test.fldComments, 
       IIf([q_sumTestReference].[fldTestsID] Is Not Null,[ConcatRef],"") AS CombinedRef, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldBiolVarNameID, q_DatasetTreatment.fldBiolVarName, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldLifeStageID, q_DatasetTreatment.fldLifeStage, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldDataTypeID, q_DatasetTreatment.fldDataType, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldGenerationID, q_DatasetTreatment.fldGeneration, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldEffectTypeID, q_DatasetTreatment.fldEffectType, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldDurationDays, q_DatasetTreatment.fldBVUnits, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldDescription AS fldBVUnitDescription, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldReportedNOEC, q_DatasetTreatment.fldReportedLOEC, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldTreatmentNum, q_DatasetTreatment.fldControlTypeID, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldControlType, q_DatasetTreatment.fldReplicateNum, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldPseudoReplicateNum, q_DatasetTreatment.fldNumberExposed,
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldMeasuredConcentration, 
       q_DatasetTreatment.fldNominalConcentration, q_DatasetTreatment.fldBiolVarValue
FROM q_sumTestReference 
RIGHT JOIN (q_Test 
            LEFT JOIN q_DatasetTreatment 
                   ON q_Test.fldTestsID = q_DatasetTreatment.fldTestsID) 
        ON q_sumTestReference.fldTestsID = q_Test.fldTestsID
ORDER BY q_Test.fldTestsID, q_DatasetTreatment.fldDatasetsID,
         q_DatasetTreatment.fldTreatmentNum, q_DatasetTreatment.fldReplicateNum;
```

I would like to use the function as it is simpler, cleaner code. Any suggestions? I see in [this post on SQL Server user-defined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902824/user-defined-function-performance-disadvantages?rq=1) that it evaluates row by row. Does this mean that a complex parsing statement in the SQL query like my 4th example is correct?

Comment: If you have a string containing digits, use `Val(your_string)` to make it sortable in numeric order.  I'm not sure you need a UDF for this, and the built-in `Val()` function could make the query faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by [HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110786/access-2007-user-defined-function-over-join-slow/18111397#comment26515499_18110786) worked:

> If you have a string containing digits, use `Val(your_string)` to make it sortable in numeric order. I'm not sure you need a UDF for this, and the built-in `Val()` function could make the query faster.

Here is the working query:

```
SELECT parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure.fldPurity,
       Val(Replace(Replace(Nz(Trim([fldPurity]),""),"%",""),"+","")) AS temp5, 
       Count(*) AS RcdCount
FROM parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure
GROUP BY parm_TestConcatReferenceDatasetExposure.fldPurity, 
         Val(Replace(Replace(Nz(Trim([fldPurity]),""),"%",""),"+",""))
ORDER BY Val(Replace(Replace(Nz(Trim([fldPurity]),""),"%",""),"+",""));
```